# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream does not implement the requested interface jakarta.mail.util.LineInputStream

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail, jakarta-migration

I'm trying to implement sending of mail template using Spring boot, but i'm constantly getting errors on jakarta's mail dependency.

Here's all of my code samples:

Email Config

```
@Configuration
public class EmailConfig {
    @Value("${spring.mail.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${spring.mail.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.mail.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        javaMailSender.setHost(host);
        javaMailSender.setPort(port);
        javaMailSender.setUsername(username);
        javaMailSender.setPassword(password);

        Properties props = javaMailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");

        return javaMailSender;
    }
}
```

Email Service

```
@Service
public class EmailServiceImpl implements EmailSender{

    @Autowired
    private  JavaMailSender mailSender;

    public void send(String to, String subject) {

        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = null;
        try {
            helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, "UTF-8");
            helper.setFrom("info@bits.com");
            helper.setTo(to);
            helper.setSubject(subject);
            helper.setText(subject, true);
            mailSender.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new CustomRequestException(e.getMessage(),
                    globaldefine.ERROR, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

My Email Template Config

```
public static String mailTemplateHelper(String title, String name, String otp){
        try {
            // Read the contents of index.html from the classpath
            String filePath = "static/index.html";
            InputStream inputStream = EmailTemplate.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
            String htmlContent = stringBuilder.toString();

            // Replace the placeholders with dynamic values
            htmlContent = htmlContent.replace("{title}", title);
            htmlContent = htmlContent.replace("{name}", name);
            htmlContent = htmlContent.replace("{otp}", String.valueOf(otp));

            // Return the modified HTML content
            return htmlContent;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Return an empty string in case of any errors
        return "";
    }
    public static String buildRegisterMail(String name, Integer otp) {
        return mailTemplateHelper("User Verification Email Template", name, String.valueOf(otp));
    } return mailTemplateHelper("User Verification Email Template", name, String.valueOf(otp));
    }
```

And finally i let spring handle the dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Error

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream does not implement the requested interface jakarta.mail.util.LineInputStream

I even tried using jakarta mail api, sun mail dependecies, getting similar errors.

Any help or leads would be appreciated.

Comment: please show all dependency version

Comment: For starters ditch your `MailConfig`, Spring Boot already configures that. Instead of writing your own templating use something like Thymeleaf or Velocity to define your templates and send those. Finally I see no connection between your mail sending and the templates. Please include your actual dependencies (your pom file) as the error clearly shows you are including more then only the starter.